# Why List<Parent> permits adding new Child but not assigning from List<Child>

Tags: c#, list, casting, covariance

This is probably a duplicate. But after a day of research I was hoping for your leniency.
It is a question about covariance.

Why can I do this?

```
List<Animal> allAnimals = new List<Animal>();
allAnimals.Add(new Dog());
allAnimals.Add(new Cat());
```

But cannot do this?

```
List<Dog> aBunchOfDogs = new List<Dog>();
allAnimals = aBunchOfDogs;
```

I have read a few discussions on covariance.

["Covariance in C#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038125/covariance-in-c-sharp)

["Converting lists to interface lists"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/7d13ac9f-3864-4afc-a213-45f3f5f92858/converting-a-list-to-a-list-of-interface-references)

["Casting list to interface list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925400/cast-listt-to-listinterface)

My understanding is, that I cannot add a list of dogs to a list of animals because then I could add a cat to the animal list, which would be dangerous. But adding a single instance of a cat or a dog to a list of animals is just as dangerous isn't it?
It seems to me that C# is undecided on whether to trust me or not.

Comment: `allAnimals = aBunchOfDogs`: now `allAnimals` is a reference to the same underlying list that `aBunchOfDogs` refers to, which is a `List<Dog>`. Now do `allAnimals.Add(new Cat())` -- oops! We added a `Cat` to our `List<Dog>`. `aBunchOfAnimals[^1]` and `aBunchOfDogs[^1]` now both return a `Cat`. That's not right!

Comment: Can't you do something like `allAnimals = aBunchOfDogs as List<Animal>;`?

Comment: @Rafalon You can try, but `allAnimals` will be `null`...

Comment: @canton7 just tried in .net fiddle, and it results in compilation error, so we can't even try it. But we can do `allAnimals = new List<Animal>(aBunchOfDogs);`

Comment: Because List<Dog> is not a List<Animal> , so it's difference , not about dangerous .

Comment: @Rafalon You can, and that's safe because it creates a *new* list -- there's no way for someone to insert a `Cat` into `allAnimals`, and for it to pop up in the `aBunchOfDogs` list

Comment: canton's comment above made me re-read the question: "*because then I could add a cat to the animal list*" - no, it's not because of that. It is because then you could add a cat to the **dog** list (by adding it to the animal list), and **that** is not possible. "*I cannot add a list of dogs to a list of animals*" - this is wrong too: you **can** add a list of dogs to a list of animals (`allAnimals = new List<Animal>(); allAnimals.AddRange(aBunchOfDogs);` should work fine). What you can't do is using the same *reference* and say somewhere it is a `List<Dog>` and elsewhere it's a `List<Animal>`

Comment: allAnimals = aBunchOfDogs <-- this line mean you want to cast aBunchOfDogs  to a allAnimals , is not add all dogs element to allAnimals. It's diffrence things. if you want to add all dogs elements , you need add dog element one by one.

Comment: Man. I think I got it all wrong. Thanks for all your help. My brain is still trying to figure it out but your comments will make that happen. It makes sense. I can add a cat or a dog or a bunch of dogs to a list of animals, because I will only ever be able to use the animal list as animals. But I can't have a list of animals be a reference to a list of dogs. Because then I could break the dog list by adding a cat. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you understand why you can pass a `Dog` and `Cat` instance to a method accepting `Animal`, here's why your latter example isn't allowed:

```
List<Dog> aBunchOfDogs = new List<Dog>();
allAnimals = aBunchOfDogs;
allAnimals.Add(new Cat()); // Fine because allAnimals is List<Animal>

foreach (var dog in aBunchOfDogs)
{
    dog.Woof(); // The Cat can't woof
}
```

Comment: Great example! Easy to understand!

Comment: Thank you Johnathan. It really hard for me to wrap my head around but it's beginning to make sense. I think unconsciously I believed "allAnimals = aBunchOfDogs" to mean "allAnimals = new List<Animal>(aBunchOfDogs)", which of course is completely wrong.

Comment: @Capricornum Yeah, the instance (runtime) type here will always be `List<Dog>`; if you were able to assign it to a `List<Animal>` variable that would only be checked at compile time; the runtime type never changes.