# "Argument type Class<T> is not assignable to parametertype Class<T1Class>" Even if Class<T> is defined with 'Where T : T1Class'

Tags: c#

Here's a simplified example that doesn't compile.

```
public class T1Class
{
}
public class Test<T> where T : T1Class
{
    public Test(IRepository repository)
    {
        repository.SavingT1Class(this);

    }
}
public interface IRepository
{
    void SavingT1Class(Test<T1Class> test);
}
```

I find it strange that the compiler cannot infer that the Test< T> class that I'm sending into SavingT1Class(Test< T1Class> test) is actually Test< T1Class> because I've defined T as T1Class.  And cannot "convert" the T into TClass.

Any Ideas how I can make the compiler understand that 'this' is actually Test< T1Class> without adding generics to IRepository itself?

Comment: If `T` is a subclass of `T1Class`, then it would be invalid to pass that `Test<T>` to the `SavingT1Class` method.

Comment: Have you tried `void SavingT1Class<T>(Test<T> test) where T: T1Class;` ?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay.  Huh that's correct.  I assumed that would be valid, in the same way that sending subclass of a parameter is allowed.  That would explain it. 

Though I cannot understand why it sending SubClass would work but Test<SubClass> wouldn't.

Comment: That's because even if `T` "is-a" `T1Class`, that doesn't make `Test<T>` "is-a" `Test<T1Class>`. The latter two are completey unrelated inheritance-wise.

Comment: @Fildor Yeah that would work, but in my case (not in the simplified example in the post) would add a lot of noise in the code that is used in tons of places.  Since there are a lot of methods in IRepository that would need to have that and those used in many places  so I'm hoping there's a more clean way.

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: @Fildor I don't see why it doesn't make Test<T> a Test<T1Class> because I've defined T as T1Class, thus Test<T> must be Test<T1Class>?

Comment: That's exactly the pitfall most people (including me) fall into, when starting out with Generics. No, Test<T> is not a Test<T1Class>. See Johnathan's link. Read it carefully and make sure you understand. I regularly revisit that section ;D

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thanks for that link.  That looks to cover my misunderstanding, going to read through that.

Comment: @Fildor Hehe, I see.  I've certainly fallen in that pitfall, will read through it.

Comment: Using a `Test<TDerived>` in place of a `Test<TBase>` would break type-safety. [Here is an example why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69673580/8126362).