# Cannot implicitly convert type when using generics with constraints

Tags: c#, generics, interface, automapper

I am trying to create a custom type converter for AutoMapper and my issue is "**Cannot implicitly convert type**"

This is my converter code:

```
public class StatusConverter<TValue> : ITypeConverter<string, Wrapper<TValue>> where TValue : Status
{
    public Wrapper<TValue> Convert(string source, Wrapper<TValue> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return Status.Create(source);
    }
}
```

The error happens on line `return Status.Create(source);`, it says can't convert from `Wrapper<Status>` to `Wrapper<TValue>`.

I have uploaded all other classes related to this here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/iSr94S

But my question is:
Why am I getting this error? I have put a constraint in the method `where TValue : Status`, so `TValue` will be of type `Status`, why is it complaining about the type?

Thanks

Comment: In short because `Wrapper<Status>` is not `Wrapper<SomeStatusInheritor>`. [Covariance and Contravariance in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) can be a useful start for investigation.

Comment: @GuruStron Could you explain what I have to look in exactly? I tried doing the following as well: `public class StatusConverter<TValue, TType> : ITypeConverter<string, Wrapper<TValue>>
            where TValue : Enumeration<TType>
            where TType : struct, IComparable
        {
            public Wrapper<TValue> Convert(string source, Wrapper<TValue> destination, ResolutionContext context)
            {
                return Status.Create(source);
            }
        }` but I got the same result.

Comment: Do you have classes which inherit from `Status` ? What does `Wrapper` actually do?

Comment: @GuruStron No, I do not. The idea is that my `Enumeration` class is the base class. All classes inheriting from it will be `sealed`. In this case `Status` will be sealed, but for demo purposes I didn't do it here. `Wrapper` will be have information such as whether the creation failed, succeeded, if failed why, and the `Value`. I simplified it in my demo only with a `Value`.

Comment: If you don't then `where TValue : Status` does not make any sense. change your code to `StatusConverter: ITypeConverter<string, Wrapper<Status>>`

Comment: I see, that helps solve the problem, thank you. One additional question, is it possible to make the generic here be `Enumeration` and make it work with all classes inheriting from it (without reflection, preferably, or is it a must in this case?)?

Comment: TBH right now without real code I would not help a lot. Maybe there is an x-y problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments reason for such behavior is that classes in C# does not support variance, i.e. `Wrapper<SomeStatusChild>` is not `Wrapper<Status>` ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038168/2501279), for example). If you don't have `Status` inheritors you can just do:

```cs
public class StatusConverter : ITypeConverter<string, Wrapper<Status>>
{
    public Wrapper<Status> Convert(string source, Wrapper<Status> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return Status.Create(source);
    }
}
```