# Generic List of List<T>

Tags: c#, list, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, why can't a List<string> object be stored in a List<object> variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable)

I thought this could work:

```
private List<DateTime> _dateTimes = new List<DateTime>();
private List<String> _strings = new List<String>();

private List<List<Object>> _listOfLists = new List<List<Object>>();

_listOfLists.Add(_dateTimes);
_listOfLists.Add(_strings);
```

But, I get a compiler error stating that the .Add method has some invalid arguments...Does anybody see why? And, what can be a solution to have a generic List of Lists?

Comment: and on which one of the two calls to .Add you get the error? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that for reasons related to type safety, you cannot treat a `List<string>` as a `List<object>`. If you could, this would be possible:

```
var list = (List<object>)(new List<string>());
list.Add((object)42); // this should never be allowed to compile
```

What you *can* do is this:

```
private List<DateTime> _dateTimes = new List<DateTime>();
private List<String> _strings = new List<String>();

private List<IList> _listOfLists = new List<IList>();

_listOfLists.Add(_dateTimes);
_listOfLists.Add(_strings);
```

This works because `List<T>` implements `IList`. Of course, you have now "forced" the compilation of the code by forfeiting compile-time type safety. In essence you accept that if you do try to add an object of incorrect type to one of the `IList` instances you will get a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

A `List<string>` is no `List<object>`. If that were the case you could cast a `List<string>` to a `List<object>` at runtime and then call the `Add` method with a type other than `string`. This would corrupt the state of the list.