# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Library.Product>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Library.IHierarchicalEntity>'

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, why can't a List<string> object be stored in a List<object> variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable)

I am having the following code.

```
   public class Manufacturer :  IHierarchicalEntity
    {
        public string ManufacturerName
        {
            get
            {
                return _manfuacturerName;
            }
            set
            {
                _manfuacturerName = value;
            }
        } private string _manfuacturerName;

        public List<Product> Products
        {
            get
            {
                return _products;
            }
        } private List<Product> _products;

        #region IHierarchicalEntity Members

        public List<IHierarchicalEntity> Children
        {
            get
            {
                return Products; //This is where I get the compiler error
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class Product :  IHierarchicalEntity{}

    public interface IHierarchicalEntity
    {
        List<IHierarchicalEntity> Children { get; }
    }
```

I get a compiler exception that

Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<Library.Product>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Library.IHierarchicalEntity>`

Both Manufacturer and Product are of type IHierarchicalEntity. Why is it not taking the `List<Product>` as `List<IHierarchicalEntity>` ?

Comment: Is there no other description of what type of list that it can't convert to? Does the compiler error literally say "...type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'"?

Comment: We get this question every single day on StackOverflow.  Take a look at any of the hundreds of "Related" questions in the link list to the right of the page.

Comment: Search for "generic variance" to find lots of similar questions and answers. (I don't have time to do so this second.)

Comment: The short answer: a list of apples is not a list of fruit. Why? Because you can put a banana into a list of fruit, but you cannot put a banana into a list of apples, so they are not the same type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This conversion is not possible, otherwise you could add a `OtherHierarchicalEntity` to `List<Product>` so its not safe. You can cast explicitly and return a new list:

```
  return Products.Cast<IHierarchicalEntity>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
return Products.ToList<IHierarchicalEntity>();
```