# Why List<T2> is not a subtype of List<T1> if T2 is a subtype of T1 in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

Why `List<T2>` is not a subtype of `List<T1>` if `T2` is a subtype of `T1`? 
What is the limitation behind that behavior?

What is the better way of workaround that limitation?

Comment: Covariance and Contravariance in Generics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable

Comment: An option would be to use IEnumerable<T1> when you want the method to support covariance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a list of dogs is not a list of animal. If it were true you could do

```
List<Animal> list = new List<Dog>();
list.Add(new Cat());
```

But adding a cat in a list of dog is not valid. You should read articles about covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 1):

Because then you could cast a list of T2 to a list of T1, loosen the criteria for insertion and then insert an object of T1 to a list whose runtime type accepts only T2.

To work around this, you can create a new list using `Cast<T1>().ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

What is just because you're talking about the `List<>`, not about `T1` and `T2`. You can make the lists convertable wrapping them by own classes and defining cast operations