# Will GPU affects the performance of video in devices?

Tags: performance, video-streaming, html5-video, jwplayer, windows-rt

We are facing a weird problem in `Surface device` with `Windows RT` operating system

When we are playing the video from `Cloudfront CDN` through `JW player`, Video takes long time to load and buffers very often than other devices. Sometimes it stops playing video. Same problem when we are using `HTML5 video player`

When we tried to play the video in `Surface pro 2`, it works fine.

What might me the problem here, it is because of `CPU`, `GPU`, `RAM` or any other browser issue in that specific device?

Simple Jwplayer Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/Ga55z/1/)  :  http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/Ga55z/1/

Simple HTML5 Player Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/dU6TF/) : http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/dU6TF/

Comment: @RobG: I removed javascript tag

Comment: This seem to be more about a networking problem than a code problem? Could you share the code you have problems with?

Comment: @Epistemex: We tried with the page that contains only JW player and HTML5 player. Same problem exists.

Comment: If the problem persists even when using a simple <video> tag, without any player script at all, then it has nothing to do with JW Player, either.

Comment: @Sathya -  
[Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself ([See Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important)), it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Sathya : How was the performance of the same player with other tablet devices like iPad, Nexus, Samsung tablet, Can you give little more information on how was it behaving with other devices, other then surface?

Comment: Yeah, have you only tested on the surface?

Answer (score 1):

The GPU of the device is only used for decoding the video. If you can watch a video locally with no problems then you can almost certainly rule out the GPU as a bottleneck.

It doesn't seem very likely that the CPU is slowing you down but you should be able to check how much of the CPUs time the video player is taking through Task Manager or something similar.

The only 2 remaining factors I can think of that would affect you are RAM and your network hardware (since you've already tried watching it on another device on the same connection I'm assuming).

I'd get some info on what network speeds your device + connection is capable of and if you can rule that out, investigate how much RAM the browser is using.