# TypeCast List<T> from TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a single MVC view to display a "Details" page for my search results, which can be of many different types (Applications, People, Computers, Licenses, etc etc)...

Given that all of these different types do NOT have the same object properties, or even the same basic properties, what I've decided to do to handle this is to pass along the list of results on the Search view, to the Details controller.

However, I am having an issue reading that information back within the controller... here's the code (partial) I have so far:

```
public ActionResult Details(int index)
    {
        List<object> SearchResults = TempData.ContainsKey("SearchItems") ? TempData["SearchItems"] as List<object> : null;
        if(SearchResults == null)
        {
            //go to error page.
            ViewBag.ErrorDescription = "Oups! Something went wrong trying to load the profile information. If you continue to see this error message, please contact the system administrator with the details below.";
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "An internal error occurred: TempData object key not found.";
            return View("Error");
        }

        if(SearchResults.Count == 0)
        {
            //go to error page.
            ViewBag.ErrorDescription = "Oups! Something went wrong trying to load the profile information. If you continue to see this error message, please contact the system administrator with the details below.";
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "An internal error occurred: TempData object contains no elements.";
            return View("Error");
        }

        //I also check if the index is out of range and stuff... 

        object TypeUse = SearchResults[0];

         //case statement and other actions are here...

    }
```

So far I can read the list by looking up the `TempData[SearchItems]` in the debugger and it shows me the correct information, BUT, for some reason as soon as I try to cast to `List<object>`, the `SearchResults` becomes null.

As you can see by the code above, the logic I follow is:

1. check if the list exists;
2. check if it's empty;
3. other checks; and
4. ONLY THEN, typecast it to it's real type via the first element in the list...

From there I would display the proper information for this type of object in the view...

So my question two fold:

1. Is my logic sound in doing this in this order?
2. Is there another way/standard way to do this?

Comment: TempData is single read FYI

Comment: yes i know and that is fine... i only need to pass along the result set and the index number through querystring... once i read it in the other controller, i can store it for that controller as just the single object.

Comment: Note that you cannot cast a `List<T>` to a `List<object>` (unless `T` _is_ `object`).  You could cast to an `IEnumerable<object>` but its not clear if that would solve your problem or not.

Comment: interesting... and why can't you cast down? I thought all "objects" inherited from `object` ?

Comment: Because it's a list of a specific type - if you could cast it to `List<object>` then you could add any object to it.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable) for more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You cannot cast a `List<T>` to a `List<object>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable) (unless `T` *is* `object`).  You could cast to an `IEnumerable<object>` and change your "first" object extraction:

```
IEnumerable<object> SearchResults = 
    TempData.ContainsKey("SearchItems") ? 
        TempData["SearchItems"] as IEnumerable<object> : 
        null;

...

object TypeUse = SearchResults.First();
```

Comment: ok... and is the logic/way i am doing this a good way or am i better off creating multiple "Details" page instead of just one?

Comment: It depends on how much type-specific code you have - if you use reflection and do different stuff based on the type then separate partial views may be cleaner.

Comment: Additionally then line `if (SearchResults.Count ==0)` will need to be changed to `if(!SearchResults.Any())`

Comment: oooookkkkkkkkk... lol. I guess i'll create a different page for each as it will be cleaner ;)

Comment: Actually if you have .Net 4.5 - `IReadonlyList<T>` might be slightly better than `IEnumerable<T>` as it still provides you with the index and count properties

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [co variance and contra variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Say `Cat` and `Dog` both inherit from `Animal`.

You might expect to be able to cast a `List<Cat>` as a `List<Animal>` e.g.

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
cats.Add(new Cat());
List<Animal> animals = (List<Animal>)cats;

Animal first = animals[0];
```

Now whilst that all looks OK, **this code won't actually work**, if this behaviour was actually allowed then how could you cope with

```
animals.Add(new Dog());
```

`Dog` is not a valid type to be stored into a `List<Cat>`.

As you want to pull out a collection of base types you can use `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = (IEnumerable<Animal>)cats;
Animal first = cats.First(); // using Linq;
```

Be warned, for similar reasons you cannot then directly cast back to `IEnumerable<Cat>` as not every `Animal` is a `Cat`. You can use the Linq extensions methods `OfType<Cat>()` or `Cast<Cat>()` to do this.

So in your case you will need `SearchResults` to be of type `IEnumerable<object>` or even a base interface/class that all of your searchable types inherit from allowing you to utilize any common properties in your logic.

**FollowUp**

If you are using .Net 4.5 you can make use of `IReadonlyList<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`.  This provides the additional advantage of still providing the count and item indexing.