# Method Argument Type to handle Dictionaries with different Key types?

Tags: c#, types

New to C#, and I am trying to pass Dictionaries with differing Key types to a method:

1. Dictionary<long, object>
2. Dictionary<string, object>

Is it possible to make my method signature flexible enough to accept both types?

I tried writing my method to be more generic:

```
public void methodName(IDictionary<object, object> pDictionary)
```

But I get the error:
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<long, object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<object, object>'

I don't totally understand why I cannot implicitly convert long to object, but I supposed it's because it's contained inside a Dictionary. Am I approaching this problem the wrong way, could it be impossible to write a method signature that can handle Dictionaries with differing Key types?

Comment: You could make `methodName` generic in the key type e.g. `public void methodName<TKey>(IDictionary<TKey, object> pDictionary)` but it's not clear how you'd be able to make use of it within the method without an argument of type `TKey`. How is the dictionary accessed within the method?

Comment: How do you propose that an unboxed `long` should be put into an `object` field? More the point, even if the `string` one: what happens if the function tries to do `pDictionary.Add(new object(), ...);`

Comment: Related: [Why can't a List<string> be stored in a List<object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6557/2791540). Same goes for dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Generic Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods). Your method might look like `public void MethodName<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)`. If you need to limit the type arguments, you can use a where constraint (`public void Method<T>() where T : IList`).